# how to calculate probability of a stock return of -20.5% (one day/daily return), assuming lognormal distribution of returns

Tags: python

I am working on a question for a course.

How can I calculate the probability of a daily return of -20.5% in S&P500 (i,e s&p500  dropping 20.5% or more in one day, this day can be tomorrow or in next 50 years)
The following are given:
Annual Volatility= 20%
Stock returns follow lognormal distributin

I am using [python](/questions/tagged/python)

```
return=-0.205
daily_standarddeviation= 0.2/sqrt(252) #annual Std divided by number of days
```

I have below questions

1. Shall I use stats.norm.cdf() or stats.lognorm.cdf()?
2. What paramaters shall I pass it? Mean and Std?
3. The mean is not mentioned in the question.so shall I calculate historical daily return?
4. The daily_std is the standard deviation of returns, not the standard deviation of log of returns. Do I need to convert the mean and std before I pass it to the function

Comment: Could you make your question more precise?  The index prices are a *process*, so exactly what event are you referring to?  A 20.5% (or greater, presumably) loss *tomorrow*?  During the next year?  Eventually?  Also, it appears you might be confusing "volume" with "volatility": if not, please explain how they are connected.

Comment: I have edited the question. Someone edited it to put volume there. I have corrected it now

Comment: Please help me convert the mean & daily standard deviation of the return for lognromal distribution. I am not sure which function shall I use. Please help me get the probability of 20.5%( or greater) loss happening tomorrow and also the same event happening eventually or in 20 years.

Comment: Daily returns are not log normal. Eventually everything happens in GBM world

Comment: Since this is for a course please add the self-study tag.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I fully understand the question, but if your asking for probabilities there is a 20 percent chance the spy will correct itself down to 210 between now and January 2018. If you look at the last 50 years every time the fed raised interest rates the market corrected it self. 2016 GDP is proof the market is ready for a correction like it did in the past. can it continue to move up and defy the market laws on interest rates? stay tune.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more precise and to the point. Please have a look and let me know. Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you supply the rationale for this answer?  Presently it reads like a set of opinions rather than statistical analysis.

Comment: The answer does not correspond to the question's context. OP wants to get the probability estimate based on distributional assumptions given in the text. The answer uses questionable heuristics or relationships beyond the context of the question